# PIC32 PWM 180 Phase Shift

Tags: pic, pwm

So I have two PWM outputs configured in my PIC32, with PWM2 duty cycle 100-PWM1 Duty Cycle, where the objective was that when PWM1=0 PWM2 would fill the rest of the cycle so an 180º phase shift I guess.
How do i implement this to work correctly?The problem is that  PWM2 generates the HLevel at 0Seconds and not when PWM1 is going L.
How do i implement this shift when I can't "read" the output ports and delays aren't viable for a variable pwm implementation.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but why does the exact phase of the PWM outputs per cycle matter, especially if you'll be varying the duty cycle continuously? Aren't you after the averaging effect?

Comment: Do you really want a 180 degree phase shift (ie one signal is a delayed version of the other) or do you actually want one signal to be the logical inverse of the other, but they keep the same time/phase relationship?

Comment: @brhans The logical inverse while keeping the time/phase relationship is what im after yes probably didn't explain myself correctly.If T=1s PWM1 has 75% duty the signal is active 0.75s and PWM2 is active from 0.75 to 1

Comment: Which PIC32 specifically are you using? I'm guessing for your question that you're not using one of the PIC32MK devices since those have complimentary PWM outputs as far as I remember.

Comment: So assuming you're using one of the others, your should be able to configure one Output Compare module in mode 1 (Init Low, Compare forces output High) and another OC module in mode 2 (Init High, Compare forces output Low). Give them the same clock source, but hold the clock disabled at first while you configure and enable the OC modules, then enable the clock. Other than the mode (1 or 2) the rest of the config for each OC module should be exactly the same. You'd then have to reset & restart them at the end of the time period (probably using a timer interrupt).

Comment: @brhans ended up using a circuit to NOT one of the pwm signals as the programming in my pic to do that ended up being way to complex for my deadline.But thank you for your help